# Runtime issue when compiling a DLL with Conan/CMake that is not present when compiling directly with Visual Studio 2017. Is it possible to solve it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, runtime, conan

I want to use a DLL build with the help of Conan/CMake (with the Visual Studio 2017 compiler). Unfortunatly it's impiossible to link the DLL with another projet without installing the Visual C++ redistribuables whereas it is possible with a DLL generated directly from Visual Studio 2017. I would like to find a way to generate a DLL that do not need any kind of new dependencies to work. Is there a solution ?

I already tried to modify the compiler's options : /MD, /MT, /MDd, /MTd,
I tried to use the compiler option to take the runtime into account : /clr, /ZW
I tried to use the linker option to take the runtime into account : /WINMD

Comment: Get each tool-chain to output their compiler and linker command lines (including all flags).  Change the non-working one so it matches the working one.

Comment: Most likely culprits: your Cmake may not be configured to make static linkages, or your Conan may not be statically linked against the windows libraries.

Comment: About the comparison of the command line I already tried this and it appears not to be the reason of my issue but in the case I am wrong what I am supposed to look at ? About the linkage of Windows runtime libraries with Conan and/or CMake do you know how I could do that ?